# CORS not allowing post request from React

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios, cors

I'm currently using the cors as middleware.
In the API if I use

```
app.use(cors())
```

or

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  "https://www.yoursite.com",
  "http://127.0.0.1:5500",
  "http://localhost:3500",
  "http://localhost:3000",
];

const corsOptions = {
  origin: (origin, callback) => {
    if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) !== -1 || !origin) {
      callback(null, true);
    } else {
      callback(new Error("Not allowed by CORS"));
    }
  },
  optionsSuccessStatus: 200,
};


app.use(cors(corsOptions))
```

In the axios post request from react I will get *{ "message": "Network Error", "name": "AxiosError"....}*

But if I use

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));
```

The request will be allowed.

Also, I'm curently requesting like this:

```
 const response = await axios.post(
        BASE_URL,
        JSON.stringify({
          crd4e_name: email,
          crd4e_password: password,
        }),
        {
          headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );
```

Comment: The second alternative sets the `Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true` header, that's why your request `withCredentials` succeeds in this case.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen So in order to only allow requests from the allowedOrigins what should I change?

Comment: Set `origin` and `credentials` in the [CORS configuration options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72922634/parse-xml-body-from-http-push-request-with-express-node-js-using-body-parser).

Answer (score -1):

Validate white listed domains for CORS in application works well in middleware also has full control to customise, you can validate allowedOrigins with `origin` received in request. You can try this one validate and do customise as required,

```
const allowedOrigins = [
  'https://www.yoursite.com',
  'http://127.0.0.1:5500',
  'http://localhost:3500',
  'http://localhost:3000',
];

const CorsOptionsDelegate = (req, callback) => {
  const allowOriginConfig = allowedOrigins;
  const allowlist = allowOriginConfig.split(',');
  const reqOrigin = req.header('Origin');

  const isWhiteListed = allowlist.some((item) => reqOrigin.includes(item));
  if (!isWhiteListed) {
    var msg = 'Not allowed by CORS';
    callback(msg, null);
  }

  callback(null, {
    origin: isWhiteListed,
    credentials: true,
    methods: ['GET', 'POST', 'DELETE', 'UPDATE', 'PUT', 'PATCH'],
  });
};

app.use(cors(CorsOptionsDelegate));
```